# Send ajax request to Google to make sure that the computer is connected to the Internet

Tags: javascript, ajax

To check my Internet connection I use this code:

```
function send(){
    $('input').ajaxError(function(){
    alert("failed");
    });
    $.get('http://www.google.com', function(data) {
    alert("success");
    });
}
```

And I call this function

```
    input type="button" value="Click to report" onclick="sent()"
```

But always I got Failed as a result...

Comment: Read about the [Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)

Comment: your function is called `send` and onclick you do `send_report`

Comment: @Topener:I just change it when I paste my code here!!!

Answer (score 0):

You should do the code you wrote but instead of using google, use "/" (your own domain, default page). That shouldn't fail.